# Required flag on f:viewParam doesn't prevent preRenderView to be called

Tags: jsf-2, viewparams

some of my viewParams are mandatory and a FacesMessage is shown when they are missing. However the system event preRenderView is excecuted with empty search parameters and thus there is a default data result returned. Is there anyway to prevent preRenderView registered methods to be executed when the required attribute is violated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<f:event type="preRenderView">` is in this construct in essence a hack/workaround. It's as its name says indeed **always** invoked before render response phase regardless of the type request (postback or not) and the validation result (fail or not). This is also in detail elaborated in this related question: [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798/what-can-fmetadata-and-fviewparam-be-used-for) This contains the following snippet which should help you further:

```
public void init() {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    if (!facesContext.isPostback() && !facesContext.isValidationFailed()) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Put the desired logic there in place of `// ...`.

In JSF 2.2, a standard solution is available in flavor of `<f:viewAction>`, also demonstrated in the aforementioned related question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at the code, but from the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html) the `preRenderView` starts before *anything* from the view is constructed. So the application wouldn't even know there's a view param to be validated.

You probably need to check for your required arguments in the event method *or* use JSF-2.2's new [f:viewAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/javaserverfaces/2.2/vdldocs/facelets/f/viewAction.html) which seems to be what you actually want.

If you can add/are already using Omnifaces, there's the the [InvokeActionEventListener](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/eventlisteners/InvokeActionEventListener), which runs after `<f:viewParam>`s are assigned:

```
<f:event listener="#{bean.myListener()}" type="postInvokeAction" />
```